# How to create database using XAMPP shell

Tags: mysql, database, shell, magento, xampp

I want to install Magento on my localhost, using xampp shell. I've been busting my ass on the same error for hours now.

**This is my code so far**

```
set folder="mystore"
set password="mypassword"
set ip="localhost"

md %folder%
cd %folder%

echo CREATE DATABASE %folder% | mysql -u root -p
```

After i do this, i get prompted to type in the password. If i do type in the password i get the **error 1045 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password yes** error, but if i just press enter, i lets me through (atleast i think) but i get another error - **error 1064 at line 1, you have an error in your sql syntax**

I've been googling solution, tried different variations like:

**CREATE DATABASE mystore**

**CREATE DATABASE "mystore"**

**CREATE DATABASE 'mystore'**

but nothing works. I've just started using xampp and shell and i'm still a newbie, so please help :(

[image]

**After another few hours i came across some linux website where i found the solution. Can't believe the answe is that easy, but i guess as long as you are newbie at one thing, you can easily miss those things. Anyway, here's the solution**

instead of "", ' ' or even nothing in CREATE DATABASE, use ``

Example.

**Not working**

```
 echo CREATE DATABASE %folder% | mysql -u root -p
```

**Working**

```
echo CREATE DATABASE `mystore` | mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Simple command line MySQL DBA question being asked in a programming section.

Comment: thanks, that's a great answer, solved my problem @FiascoLabs